# UIImage from PNG binary from BLOB SQlite. Binary created from PHP fread. Null issue

Tags: php, objective-c, sqlite, uiimage, binary-data

I am trying to load png images into UIImage from a SQlite database. The images are stored as binaries in a blob column. I've created the binaries using PHP fread, so I guess my first question is: is this a form of output that objective c will be able to use? If this isn't causing issues, then there must be an error somewhere in my objective c code.

Here is how I load the data:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(selStmt, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(selStmt, 2)];
```

When I NSLog data, I am able to see the numbers (a long list) for the 7 images I currently have. I assume I am getting the data from the column.

What is strange is that when I send this data to an UIImage, I get nulls:

```
item.archThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

or

```
UIImage *theimage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
theimage =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

My second question is: am I missing an extra step?

Here is the method I am using to read the items from the database:

```
-(void)readItems{
if (!database) return; // earlier problems

// build select statement
if (!selStmt)
{
    const char *sql = "SELECT items.arch_id, items.arch_name, arch_thumbs.thumbs_image FROM items LEFT JOIN arch_thumbs ON items.arch_id = arch_thumbs.thumbs_arch_id ORDER BY items.arch_name ASC;";
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        selStmt = nil;
    }
}
if (!selStmt)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Can't build SQL to read items [%s]", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

// loop reading items from list
int ret;
while ((ret=sqlite3_step(selStmt))==SQLITE_ROW) 
{ // get the fields from the record set and assign to item
    // primary key
    NSInteger n = sqlite3_column_int(selStmt, 0); 
    Item *item = [[Item alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:n]; // create item
    // item name
    char *s = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selStmt, 1);
    if (s==NULL) s = "";
    item.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)s];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(selStmt, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(selStmt, 2)];

    if (sqlite3_column_blob(selStmt, 2) != NULL) {
    item.archThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    NSLog(@"the image is:%@", item.archThumb);
    }
    else{
    NSLog(@"read a NULL image");
    }

    [items addObject:item]; // add to list
    [item release]; // free item
    [data release];
}
sqlite3_reset(selStmt); // reset (unbind) statement
```

}

Comment: PHP in some cases adds slashes to variables did you check that? Is the blob content equal to file contents? This may cause that issue...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?